# Batch script calling its own name instead of files of a certain type?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, ffmpeg

```
cd %cd%
ffmpeg -i %cd%/%04d.png out.mp4
```

A script with just this in it works completely fine and outputs exactly what I need it to, but:

```
:: A simple script to convert a png or jpg image sequence to an         
mp4 file with ffmpeg
cls
@echo off
title PNG2MP4
color C
echo Ensure you have ffmpeg installed and setup in your environment variables or this script won't work.


:QUERY
echo This will convert all image files in the following directory to a single mp4, 
echo %cd%
echo are the files PNGs or JPEGs(PNG/P/JPG/J/CANCEL)?
set/p "ch=>"
if /I %ch%==PNG goto CONVERTPNG
if /I %ch%==P goto CONVERTPNG
if /I %ch%==JPG goto CONVERTJPG
if /I %ch%==J goto CONVERTJPG
if /I %ch%==CANCEL goto :eof
echo Invalid choice & goto QUERY

:CONVERTPNG
cd %cd%
ffmpeg -i %cd%/%04d.png out.mp4

:CONVERTJPG
cd %cd%
ffmpeg -i %cd%/%04d.jpg out.mp4
```

This more complex version of the script fails, outputting:

```
C:\tmp/img2mp4.bat4d.jpg: No such file or directory
```

Why is it no longer calling the files that it did before and is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: Running ffmpeg -i %04d.png out.mp4 from the command line gave me the output desired and I wanted to flesh this out in a script so I could automate doing this, I pulled the %04d syntax from a post to do with batch ffmpeg commands, and this sounds unsuitable for my use case. I have a directory of files that will be 0001.png and so on, how would I tell ffmpeg to take these in with the batch script?

Comment: Unrelated to issue in question, but I recommend adding `-vf format=yuv420p` to output a compatible chroma subsample scheme. Otherwise you may get yuv444p which dumb players can't decode (assuming you are encoding with libx264).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion for the batch file:

```
@echo off
rem A simple script to convert a png or jpg image sequence to an mp4 file with ffmpeg
cls
title PNG2MP4
color C
echo Ensure you have ffmpeg installed and setup in your environment variables
echo or this script won't work.
echo/
echo This will convert all image files in the following directory to a single mp4:
echo/
echo %cd%
echo/
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C PJC /N /M "Are the files PNGs or JPEGs or Cancel (P/J/C)? "
if errorlevel 3 color & goto :EOF
echo/
if errorlevel 2 (
    ffmpeg.exe -i %%04d.jpg out.mp4
) else (
    ffmpeg.exe -i %%04d.png out.mp4
)
color
```

The character `%` must be escaped in a batch file with one more `%` to be interpreted as literal character which was the main problem causing the batch file not working as expected. `%0` references the string used to start the batch file which was `img2mp4.bat`. So `%04d.jpg` concatenated `img2mp4.bat` with `4d.jpg` and the result was running `ffmpeg.exe` with `img2mp4.bat4d.jpg` as file name instead of the argument string `%04d.jpg`.

To reference one or more files/folders in current directory the file/folders can be simply specified in arguments list of a script or application with no path. This is explained in Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). This page describes further that on Windows the directory separator is the backslash character `\` and not the forward slash `/` as on Linux and Mac. `/` is used on Windows mainly for options as it can be seen on line with command **CHOICE** because of this character is not possible in file/folder names. `-` is used on Linux/Mac for options which is possible also in file/folder names even as first character of a file/folder name. So on Windows `\` should be always used as directory separator although the Windows kernel functions for file system accesses automatically correct `/` in file/folder names to `\`.

**CHOICE** is much better for prompting a user to take a choice from several offered options than the command **SET** with option `/P`. `set/p` is syntactically not correct at all because of command `set` should be separated with a space from option `/P` which should be separated with a space from next argument `variable=prompt text`. `set/p` forces `cmd.exe` to automatically correct the command line to `set /p`. Batch files should be syntactically correct coded and not depend on automatic error corrections of Windows command processor.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains how to reference batch file arguments.
- `echo /?`
- `rem /?`
- `cls /?`
- `title /?`
- `color /?`
- `set /?`
- `choice /?`
- `if /?`
- `goto /?`

Further I suggest to read:

- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)
- [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)
- [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564)
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)
- [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)
- [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)